# Meaning of exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have this in one of my scripts. I couldn't understand what does 1000 mean here. If anyone can help me with that.

```
if [ "$1" = "--help" ]
then
more help.txt
exit 1000
fi
```

Comment: Did you even *attempt* to look it up? E.g. `man bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Exit status

when you want to test if the previous command was ran correctly or not, you should run echo $?

echo **$?** shows that the ***previous command status.***
for example: you dont have t1.txt file in this directory

```
$ls t1.txt
$echo $?
1
```

it shows that the last command was unsuccessful
but if you had that the output of  "echo $?" would be 0

### now in your example

```
$ ./your_script.sh  --help
$echo $?
1

$ ./your_script.sh  --a
$echo $?
0
```

because you wrote in script that ***if the input was --help the exit status is unsuccessful***

### some exit codes

in your example the exit code was 1000, I'm not familiar with this one. I wrote down some popular exit codes

1 Catchall for general errors

2 Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)

126 Command invoked cannot execute

127 "command not found"

128 Invalid argument to exit

128+n Fatal error signal "n"

130 Script terminated by Control-C

255 Exit status out of range

Comment: Your answer is promising, but slightly confusing. Wasn't the exit code in the OP's example `1000`? If you improve it I will upvote it.

Comment: I actually don't know the meaning of "1000 exit code". but ok I will make it better as much as I can